# Serving HTTP Requests and Files using same server in Go Lang

Tags: http, go

Hi I am trying to create a server in Go Lang which serves files and HTTP Requests at the same time.

I want `/upload` path to accept post requests and 
`/files` path to serve static files in the `fpath`

I tried with the following code but i get a 404 error

```
func main() {
    fpath, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    fpath+="/public"
    fmt.Println(fpath)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload",uploadFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/files",http.FileServer(http.Dir(fpath)))
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: you don't mention at all what kind of technology you are using...

Comment: oops i just added the tag

Comment: You should check out [http.StripPrefix](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix). Right now, your `http.FileServer` is trying to serve routes like "/files/foo" (and thus looking for "./public/files/foo") instead of stripping the "/files" prefix off. I tried this myself and it still didn't work, so there's probably something else wrong, but you'll definitely need to do that anyway.

Comment: Try `http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(fpath))))` instead of `HandleFunc()`. Please note the trailing slashes on `"/files/"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need trailing slashes on your handle path if it's a directory. See http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux for more info.

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash).

Try

```
func main() {
    fpath, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    fpath+="/public"
    fmt.Println(fpath)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload",uploadFunc)
    http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(fpath))))
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```